# CSS targeting select option with display:none not working in Safari and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, safari

I have come across a strange CSS issue.

I have a drop down selector like this HTML markup:

```
<select id="cat_p" name="cat_p" onchange="ListChildCategories(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, 0);" class="required validate-list">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">- Choose a category</option>
    <option value="1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="3">Category 3</option>
    <option value="4">Category 4</option>
    <option value="5">Category 5</option>
</select>
```

Now, I want to hide one of these select option (let´s say Category 5) using CSS, so I use this CSS code:

```
select#cat_p option[value="5"] {
display: none;
}
```

And the result is perfect in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari and IE this CSS does not work.
I have checked in Safari developers panel and I can see that the CSS is registered as valid and it is not "crossed out" / overwritten by other CSS, so it should work, I would think.. very weird..

Does anyone have a clue what the problem is here?

I made a fiddle so you can see the problem first hand:
http://jsfiddle.net/wH8kF/

Comment: Select (and other form elements) are really hard to style consistently across all browsers, [this article](http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/) on CSS Tricks might give you some ideas.

Comment: Yes, it seems there is no real solid cross-browser CSS-only solution for hiding select option elements. I solved my own specific problem by altering the PHP script generating the HTML  - so no need for CSS anymore, but as a CSS-guy I would have preferred if there were not this kind of compatibility lack in certain CSS-styling options.. Ah well, things are never easy I suppose :)

Comment: I'm a CSS guy too so I delved into this problem a couple of months ago. This issue arrises because each browser implements the elements in another way. Look up Shadow DOM if you want to learn more ;)

Comment: What version of Chrome did this work in? I'm testing in versions 32, and 34. Your fiddle doesn't work for me in either of them.

Comment: #Cas, thanks for the info, I will look into that.
#Jonathan, I´m using the latest version of Chrome, but the problem is not in Chrome. As far as I have tested the "display:none" is not working only in IE and Safari. As you can see in the fiddle I made the select option is hidden when you use Chrome. Try to load the fiddle in IE or Safari instead and you can see that the select option is not hidden.

Comment: You can use the attribute disabled="disabled" . It doesn't hide the option, but it is not selectable. To manipulate that with jQuery, you can use .removeAttr('disabled') and .attr('disabled', 'disabled') . (it does not answer the original question, but it might be of sole help).

Comment: Were there any work arounds found for this? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: Yes, in my case the work-around was to simply modify the select element from within the PHP script that generated the HTML output. So, the CSS issue remains but in my case the problem was solved solely by a bit of clever PHP programming..

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `toggle` or `display:none` property or the hide/show with select option in the Safari browser. It is working for all other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, etc. This is part of a long and inconsistent tradition with Safari restricting CSS styling functionality on form elements, believing the visual language of interactive elements should be consistent with the OS (no point trying to find a rationale for IE's failings).

Your only options are either to remove it (and re-append it later), or to set it to `optnz.disabled = true`. Sorry for the bad news!