# hide entire blue/black dropdown (options) of empty select

Tags: html, css

I have an empty select list on which i have binded custom drop down.
On clicking on empty select, it comes into focus and shows the empty option list(which is blue in color with black border)
Is there a way in css so that we can hide that entire empty option section.

```
<select id="displaydropdown"></select> <!--empty select list-->
<script>
   //on displaydropdown click show/hide custom dropdown
</script>
```

In this case custom drop down is visible, along with that empty select list is also visible. i want to hide that internal list box of select list. Currently i am looking into user agent stylesheets to see whether we can override its default functionality.

Please let me know if anymore details.

Comment: We can give details if you post your code here.

Comment: post the code which you tried sofar?

Comment: You could use display: none;

Comment: Since its hard to manage styling select options with crossbrowser compatibility i think there's no css-only solution.check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831580/css-targeting-select-option-with-displaynone-not-working-in-safari-and-ie

Comment: I tried to add outline:none property on select:focus event, some how i want to hide that internal list box

Comment: Better you post some codes..

Comment: Better you Go through This Stackoveflow link > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css

Answer (score 0):

Try this described in this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/bs2ow5Lr/1/):

**HTML:**

```
<select id="displaydropdown"></select>
```

**CSS:**

```
#displaydropdown:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: i want to hide the default  internal list box/ menulist of select tag and not the select tag itself. If you try clicking on empty select you can see blue/black dropdown. i want to hide that. its default browser functionality.